# Asp.net core How to use indexOf in linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq statement:

```
var fliteredAddressLocations = addressLocations
    .Where(c => (c.StateId == companyStateID) && 
    (c.Suburb.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)).ToList();
```

If I remove the section after the "&&" and run it - it works return some 3000 items.

As it is it returns 0 items.

I suspect I have written it incorrectly and have tried a number of ways of constructing it including making several seperate statements.

Its a search function to search for a set of suburbs that contain the characters in "query" and with a stateId of companyStateId.

How should you write this using indexOf so that it returns the subset?

Comment: It should work f.e. if `Suburb` is `Kensington` and `query` is `Sing`, not vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, this code looks correct. What is the value of query?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally managed to solve how to use built in SQL functions in EF core, which are not included in the EF via EF.Functions.

Without further explanation, put this in your Db Context file:

```
[DbFunction("CHARINDEX", IsBuiltIn = true)]
public static long CHARINDEX(string substring, string string)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And use the same template for importing any other SQL function.

@edit:
As explained in the comments pay close attention to types. My mistake was using the wrong overload methods of string object. I used IndexOf(**char** input) instead of IndexOf(**string** input).

Would recommend checking the [Functions mapping table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) for details!

Comment: Not necessary. It's already supported (at least in theEF-core-3  Sql Server provider). Not the part `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` though, but functions like this depend on the database collation anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've had already installed used Sql server provider before, and tried using some of the build in functions, like IndexOf or Contains on a string variable in LINQ, but every time I've got the exception of EF not being able to transform my query to SQL. After check the list [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) what I found is that it says stringValue.IndexOf(value) not string.IndexOf(...). This is my only explanation of why I cant get it working without the exception. Any idea whats the difference between string and stringValue?

Comment: "string" denotes the static string methods. "stringValue" the instance methods. If there is a string variable `name`, then `name.IndexOf(value)` can be used. Or in the query above: `c.Suburb.IndexOf(query)`. It's supported.

Comment: Upvoted because the built-in support for IndexOf seems to work only with literal strings. It doesn't permit operations like
OrderBy( it => myString.IndexOf( ";" + it.SubString + ";" )
A DbFunction works fine. Use OnModelCreating:

[DbFunction( "CHARINDEX", IsBuiltIn = true )]
public static int CHARINDEX( string substring, string str, int start ) => throw new NotImplementedException();
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial( ModelBuilder modelBuilder ) {
 modelBuilder
  .HasDbFunction( typeof( LogiProContext ).GetMethod( nameof( CHARINDEX ) ) )
  .HasName( "CHARINDEX" );
}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `IndexOf` isn't being properly translated into SQL.

You could try using `Contains` instead:

```
   var fliteredAddressLocations = addressLocations
        .Where(c => (c.StateId == companyStateID) && 
        (c.Suburb.Contains(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experiments using an SQL Server Compact DB and Linq2Sql (not EF), this statement works fine:

```
from p in Places
where p.Name.IndexOf("Ew") > -1
select p
```

Return the row where Name is "New York".  If I add the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` it fails (throws an exception), but, in this case at least, the search is case-insensitive without the parameter.

Note that you can also use

```
from p in Places
where p.Name.Contains("Ew")
select p
```

which has the same effect and is a bit clearer.